# How to hide header and search component in other component using navigation?

Tags: angular

**Current Code:**
I have two components (app-header,app-search), both components integrated in app.component.html like below.

```
<app-header></app-header><app-search></app-search>
```

and I am using navigation to go to other component like user:app-user.

**Problem:**
Issue is i tried to hide the header and search components like using below code
in user.component.ts:

```
show: boolean = false;
```

and user.component.html code written given below

```
<div *ngIf="show"><app-header></app-header><app-search></app-search></div>
```

***But header and search components showing, Kindly help me to hide the search and header components when using navigation to user?***

Comment: does ur `app.component.html` have `<router-outlet>` ?

Comment: Logically there is nothing wrong with your code. Can you maybe create an Angular Snippet where we can see all components, etc.?

Comment: Yes i have used router

Comment: Going to user component working fine, but I need to hide header and search component in user component. Kindly help me

Comment: Let me understand the problem first.
app.component.html has - app-header and app-search.
`<app-header></app-header><app-search></app-search>`

In, user.component.html, you are trying to add app-header and app-search again and trying to hide them.
`<div *ngIf="show"><app-header></app-header><app-search></app-search></div>`

Comment: Exactly but in user.component.html I don't want any components. header and search components automatically displaying when we are navigate to user component

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve solution this way.

Create service, which has a `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` property with initial value as true, BehaviorSubject is choosen because it emits the default value when the BehaviorSubject is subscribed for the first time.

```
@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {
 private showOrHideHeader = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true); // First 
 subscription value will be true.
 // This method returns a BehaviorSubject that you can subscribe to, or emit new value from.
 getHeaderFlag() {
  return this.showOrHideHeader;
 }
}
```

Inject HeaderService in AppComponent. and subscribe to `showOrHideHeader` BehaviorSubject in ngOnInit. You can get the `showOrHideHeader` by calling this.headerService.getHeaderFlag()

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template:`<div *ngIf="show"> <app-header></app-header> <app-search> </app-sear‌​ch></div>,`
providers: [HeaderService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 private show: boolean = true;
 constructor(private headerService : HeaderService ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.headerService.getHeaderFlag().subscribe((flag)=>{
   this.show = flag;
 });
}
}
```

In UserComponent, Inject the HeaderService and do `.next(false)` on the `showOrHideHeader` BehaviorSubject which is returned from the headerService.getHeaderFlag() method.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-user',
template: `<div> User </div>`,
providers: [HeaderService]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private headerService : HeaderService ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  let headerFlagSubj = this.headerService.getHeaderFlag();
  headerFlagSubj.next(false);
 }
}
```

You can provide `HeaderService` in AppModule so you dont have to provide `HeaderService` in these two components.

Comment: I didn't checked in console. it's going to user component fine. but showing error " ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'." in appComponent.html.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is app-header and app-search are in app-component.html.
You are not specifying condition in AppComponent to whether or not to show app-header and app-search in app-component.html.
One thing you can do is, use a flag in app-component.html, like below.

`<div *ngIf="show"><app-header></app-header><app-search></app-sear‌​ch></div>`

You can set this `show` flag using any of the following methods.

1. You can use @Output event bindings to emit **false** when the UserComponent is loaded. You can do emit on ngOnInit() method of UserComponent. Then use this emitted value in AppComponent to set the `show` flag.
2. You can use the Router in AppComponent.ts. when the page navigates to "UserComponent", you can set `show` to false (In AppComponent.ts).
3. You can use a service to do it. Create a service. Inject in AppComponent and in UserComponent. 
   create Subject in the service 
   `let $showOrHideAppHEader = new Subject<boolean>()`. 
   In AppComponent, Subscribe to `$showOrHideAppHEader` Subject in in constructor or in ngOnInit.
   `this.$showOrHideAppHEader.subscribe((flag) => {
   this.show = flag;
   });`

And when the UserComponent is loaded do `$showOrHideAppHEader.next(false)`.

Comment: Basavaraj:,I have updated below code in app.component.html. <div *ngIf="show"><app-header></app-header><app-search></app-sear‌​ch></div>

and below code is updated in app.component.ts show: boolean = false;   but what happen is total header and search not showing in entire application. Kindly help me

Comment: Basaravaj: work flow is while loading application i have added header and search components in app.components.html, and once search user and click on button page will go to user component. In user component i dont want search component. Kindly help me

Comment: Basavaraj:for example localhost:4200/user then it will show only user details not header and search components